# How to enforce TypedDict structure in a class

Tags: python, python-typing

I was wondering how to utilize `TypedDict` in my own class in an ORM-like application im building. Here is my best try:

I have the following `TypedDict`:

```py
class ConcreteOptions(TypedDict):
    one: str
    two: str
```

(Now the non-functioning part) Theres a class like this:

```py
class Database(Generic[VT]):
    def __init__(self, options: Dict[str, Any]):
        self.options = cast(VT, options)

    def __getitem__(self, k: str) -> VT:
        return self.options[k]
```

An instance of that class would get initialized like this:

```py
opts: ConcreteOptions = {"one": "1", "two": "2"}
db: Database[ConcreteOptions] = Database(opts)
```

The desired behavior would allow me to get items from the instance via

```py
val_one = db["one"]
val_two = db["two"]
```

while having correct type inference and intellisense in the IDE.

Having the ability to use `Database[SomeOptions]` is the key of what im trying to achieve as thats the way the end user will enforce some types on the underlying object.

Comment: I don't quite get the point of this. It looks like you want to wrap a ``TypedDict`` to... define what is effectively a ``TypedDict``? How would the ``Database[ConcreteOptions]`` differ from just using ``ConcreteOptions``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for pointing that out. The `Database` class has, of course, more methods than whats shown above. The point of wrapping is that the `options` attribute comes from an external source - from a JSON and casting it to a `TypedDict` would provide type hints. 
Note: I know that casting may raise some errors but thats up for the user to check.

Comment: Probably similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74110541/14190526