# Python TypeDict enforce, convert dict to TypeDict

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to convert regular `dict` to `TypedDict`, so only specified keys will be present in a new dict?

Example:

```
incorrect_dict = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
correct_dict = only_a_dict = {'a': 'a'}

assert some_typed_dict_with_only_a(**incorrect_dict) == only_a_dict
```

With dataclasses we can do this:

```
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class MyDC:
    a: int

my_dc = MyDC(**correct_dict)  # Ok
my_dc = MyDC(**incorrect_dict)  # Error, unexpected keyword argument 'b' (Ok)
```

What I want is:

```
import typing


class MyTD(typing.TypedDict):
    a: int

my_dc = MyTD(**correct_dict)  # Ok
my_dc = MyTD(**incorrect_dict)  # Should be error here! (not Ok)
```

I'm know that `TypedDict` is only type checking feature, not validation feature, but anyway.
Apparently I should make a `dataclass` from `TypedDict` somehow or...

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the keys in the dict to the type annotations of your class:

```
class MyTD(typing.TypedDict):
    a: int
    
    @classmethod
    def from_dict_strict(cls, dict_):
        if set(typing.get_type_hints(cls)) != set(dict_):
            raise TypeError('Input dict has too many or too few keys')
        
        return cls(**dict_)
```

```
my_dc = MyTD.from_dict_strict(correct_dict)  # Ok
my_dc = MyTD.from_dict_strict(incorrect_dict)  # Throws error
```

Comment: The good one solution, but I personally can't call this "Just" :)
The "just" meant only one line one code without self-made methods that should exists in the tests eventually.